# A problem about the composition factors of group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

There is my problem:

Let G be a finite group with composition factors $G_1,G_2,...,G_n$, Assume that $G_i$ not isomorphism $G_j$ for all $i \ne j$. Suppose that for any $\sigma \in S_n$, there exists a composition series $1=M_0 \lhd 
 M_1 \lhd 
...\lhd 
M_n=G$ such that $M_k/M_{k-1} \cong 
G_{\sigma (k)}$ for $k=1,...,n$. Then $G$ has to be the product group $G_1\times ...\times G_n
$.

I try to do it by induction, then will have composition series of $M_{n-1}$, and $M_{n-1}$ will equal to product of $n-1$ group in $G_1,...,G_n$, then we can get $G$ has normal subgroup $G^{(k)}=G_1 \times ...\times G_{k-1} \times G_{k+1} \times ...G_{n}$, $k=1,...,n$, and subgroup $G_1,...,G_n$, but then I donnot know if use those infomation can get $G_1\times ...\times G_n.
$

Comment: I think you mean $G_i \not\cong G_j$ rather than $G_i \ne G_j$.

Comment: Do you know the criterion to recognise an internal direct product?

Comment: Can you do it for $n=2$?

Comment: @Steve D No,I only can get $G/G_1=G_2$, and $G/G_2=G_1$, and $G$ has subgroup $G_1$,$G_2$.

Comment: @verret I know,but I cannot get $G_i$ are normal subgroup of $G$,and G equal to $G_1G_2...G_n$.

Comment: @Steve D Oh, I can,when n=2, I can get $G_1$,$G_2$ are normal subgroup,and then I can use criterion of internal direct product. but if n>2, I cannot get G_i are normal subgroup.

Comment: You have $G_1 \times \cdots \times G_{n-1}$ normal, and $G_1$ is characteristic in $G_1 \times \cdots \times G_{n-1}$ (it is the only normal subgroup isomorphic to $G_1$), so $G_1$ is normal in $G$. Similarly for all $G_i$.

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $\times$ using `\cdots`.